# Random and list slicing working strangely with online world list

Tags: python, random

I really don't know how to use python to interact with the internet. I can't seem to find any beginner learning for it besides a codeacademy course.

Anyway I wanted to try and make a hangman game with a randomly selected word from an english dictionary. 
I just need a world list which I have not definitions. I can get it to print out the entire world list but things aren't acting right when I try to select a specific portion of it or just run it through random.choice()

```
import urllib
import random
webpage = urllib.urlopen("http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/wordlists/english/wordlist/wordsEn.txt").read()
print random.choice(webpage)
```

is all I currently have I tried printing webpage[0: ] or webpage[0: 10] or some random number and it the first doesn't really work at all the second prints 3 words or 3 pieces of words on separate lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the words is on a separate line in the file, when you open the url you get a large string of words with new line characters. To get around this you need to split up the string into separate lines.

Luckily python has inbuilt methods for most things in this case if you add:

```
webpage = webpage.splitlines()
```

between the 3rd and 4th line it will work, resulting in the following code:

```
import urllib
import random
webpage = urllib.urlopen("http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/wordlists/english/wordlist/wordsEn.txt").read()
webpage = webpage.splitlines() # Split text into lines.
print random.choice(webpage)
```

Answer (score 0):

`random.choice` selects a single random element from the sequence that you input.  Your `webpage` is a string (which is a sequence of 1-character strings), so `random.choice` is going to pick a single character at random, not a single word.

The trick is to break your string (`webpage`) into a sequence of strings (words).  Depending on the original data, this can probably be accomplished via some invocation of `webpage.split` or `webpage.splitlines`

e.g.

```
words = webpage.split()
print random.choice(words)
```